# Excel spreadsheet having line breaks

Tags: excel, powershell, newline, line-breaks

I have excel spread sheet where NSG rules are added in that excel spread sheet. I am writing PowerShell code to check the completely excel sheet if any line breaks are present in the sheet (attached the screenshot and highlighted in the red color) and if any line break exists then convert the values by removing the line break and add the comma before that value. I have tried the requirement with below code, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77767717/45375):

```
$path = "./NSG_Rules.xlsx"
$rows = Import-Excel $path

# Get the column (property) names
$propNames = $rows[0].psobject.Properties.Name

$rowsToDeleteIndices = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] @()

# Process all rows, expanding the cells of merged columns into individual rows.
$rowIndex = 1 # Start with 1, to account for the header row.
foreach ($row in $rows) {
    ++$rowIndex

    foreach ($propName in $propNames) {
        $propValue = $row.$propName

        # Check if the value contains a comma and needs to be expanded
        if ($propValue -match ',') {
            $values = $propValue -split ','

            # Update the current row with the first value
            $row.$propName = $values[0]

            # Create new rows for the remaining values
            for ($i = 1; $i -lt $values.Count; $i++) {
                $newRow = $row.psobject.Copy()
                $newRow.$propName = $values[$i]
                $rows += $newRow
            }
        }
    }
}

# Export the modified values back to the worksheet,
# in place, with all formatting preserved.
# Via -PassThru, obtain a reference to the package (workbook),
# for advanced operations such as row deletion.
$pkg = $rows | Export-Excel $path -PassThru

# Obtain a reference to the first worksheet again
# (the same one implicitly targeted by Import-Excel / Export-Excel).
$ws = $pkg.Workbook.Worksheets[1]

# Now delete the no longer needed rows with merged columns from it.
$i = 0
$rowsToDeleteIndices | ForEach-Object { $ws.DeleteRow($_ + $i--) }

# Close and thereby implicitly save the package.
Close-ExcelPackage $pkg`
```

my requirement is the excel spread sheet should update by removing the line breaks and add comma to that value. I am trying to get the same format of the input sheet as well as in the output.

Below are the screenshots for reference:

[image]

expected output in after code execution:
[image]

Note: I have raised same type of question earlier but this requirement is quite different compared to other questions and sorry for raising multiple questions.

Comment: If the line breaks are truly part of the same cell, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77748624/45375) should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @mklement0. Thanks for the updated. I have used the code which you have mentioned in another question and it is working fine. but one small issue I am facing in the output sheet. In the excel spreadsheet I have column with name "DestinationPortrange" (attached the same in screenshot) . After executing the script the port values are changing like "2021" and comma is not adding between 20 and 21.

Comment: You've hit an edge case: String `20,21` is interpreted _as a number_ by `Export-Excel` and therefore becomes `2012` (the `,` is interpreted as a thousands-grouping mark). The solution is to use the `-NoNumberGrouping` parameter. I've updated the linked answer to show a solution. Your question should be closed as a duplicate of the linked post, but as long as no answers either have up-votes or there's an accepted answer, it cannot be.

Comment: Hi @mklement0. Thanks for the update. My issue is resolved.